# How to disable "scroll compression" in ScrollViewer

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

In a template I'm using a ScrollViewer with the following properties:

```xml
<ScrollViewer
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
    HorizontalSnapPointsType="MandatorySingle"
    HorizontalSnapPointsAlignment="Near"
    ZoomMode="Disabled">
    <ItemsPresenter/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

This works mostly fine. The only detail I want to change is to disable "scroll compression" when the scroll viewer is scrolled to either the leftmost/rightmost positions. At these positions, if I touch and drag past the beginning/end then the contents of the ScrollViewer is compressed slightly to indicate that scrolling in that direction is not possible.

Is there a way to disable this behavior?

Comment: Did you find any solution for that? Maybe custom scrollviewer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot turn the overbounce (what we call it) off if the content is larger than the viewport.  If the content will absolutely fit within the viewport of the `ScrollViewer` you can set `ScrollMode=Auto`, but this will only not overbounce if it fits.